# Google Maps Styling API. Adjust transparency/opacity

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I understand that Google Maps Styling API can be used to configure the display of the Map on a device. I wanted to know whether it is possible to make this view transparent (or in my case more "translucent").

I want to draw the entire map as a kind of an overlay, with an average opacity so as to appear as a translucent overlay over the background. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my Google Maps documentation, there wasn't a styling property for transparency.

I solved this by changing the opacity of the google maps style element.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
  $('.gm-style').css("opacity", 0.65)
});
```

This isn't a perfect solution since the entire map gets more transparent - the background and the font/roads. I would prefer a way to make the background more transparent than the important information (roads/text) for a sharper contrast.

A better solution would be welcome.